# Outgoing email of SharePoint server not working

Tags: sharepoint-email, smtp, outgoing-email

After Change our SMTP server change to **Office 365**,server not sent any mail(outgoing mail)

I have already Configure **outgoing email for a farm**
and
Configure outgoing email for a **specific web application**

for new SMTP server name as per [Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc263462.aspx)

Is any way to debug SMTP service
or else any configuration any more,In that

Comment: Is there any set-up while install SMTP service?

Answer (score 6):

For debug purposes, you can do a few things.

First is to use the [`Send-MailMessage`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) cmdlet. This is an alternative to using [`telnet`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/153119) to test SMTP functionality. If neither of these work, I would take a look at the SMTP server logs. Those logs may show that the SMTP server is dropping the mail due to access permissions (perhaps scoped IP range on a receive connector) or dropping mail if it requires authentication (SharePoint 2010/2013 can only send anonymous mail over tcp/25). You could also look at the SharePoint server, perhaps it has host-based A/V that blocks outgoing tcp/25. Make sure that `nlsookup` and `tracert` show the correct information from the SharePoint server to your SMTP server hostname. And of course, there could be a firewall issue, inbound on the SMTP server or outbound on the SharePoint server.

If `Send-MailMessage` *does* work, you can try sending email from SharePoint using PowerShell:

```
$email = "alias@company.com"
$subject = "Email through SharePoint OM"
$body = "Message body."

$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite "http://siteUrl"
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::SendEmail($web,0,0,$email,$subject,$body)
```

While you're running this, use [ulsviewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020) to monitor the ULS logs on the SharePoint server and filter to the "E-Mail" category. This should give you information on not only what SharePoint is attempting to connect to, but any potential errors it is encountering.

Comment: it gives false in Management shell Screen ,Or not any specific "email" related log @trevor

Comment: The ULS logs filtered by catagory:email had the real logs, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had to add my local IP to the SMTP server allow list, not just 127.0.0.1 http://sharepointbulletin.blogspot.com/2014/03/mailbox-unavailable-server-response-was.html