# sharepoint outgoing email notification not working

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, web-part, email, alert

Good day,
Kindly assist.  sharepoint does not send email notifications. Our SharePoint Server is configured for Out-going E-Mail settings-port 25, Exchange server allows SharePoint to Send Mails. Regardless it's still not sending notifications.

Thank you for helping

Comment: You are configured alerts ? please check any logs in eventviewer and uls logs, please check it helpful https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166040/outgoing-email-of-sharepoint-server-not-working

Comment: i have checked before and it did not help..